# Triple DES Encrytion in GWT and Decryption in Javascript

Tags: java, encryption, gwt, cryptojs, tripledes

I need to do triple DES encryption in GWT client file and need to do decryption of encrypted string in javascript. I have used TripleDesCipher in GWT but while doing decryption in javascript using crypto-js, I am getting blank string. Following is my GWT code.

```
    TripleDesCipher cipher = new TripleDesCipher();
    String enc ="";
    String key = "579D2D852F2F3BABABBD71B7";

    cipher.setKey(key.getBytes());
    try {
      enc = cipher.encrypt(String.valueOf(value));


    } catch (DataLengthException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidCipherTextException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Following is my javascript code for decryption.

```
var encrypted = urlParams.get('id');

var base64String = encrypted.toString();
alert(base64String);
var key = "579D2D852F2F3BABABBD71B";        

var decrypted = 
CryptoJS.TripleDES.decrypt(base64String,key);
console.log("DES3 decrypted text:"+ decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```